# jQuery validate not working with TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm having a problem with jQuery validate on my ASP.NET MVC 4 site. Here's the form:

```
@model QuestionModel

@using ( Html.BeginForm() ) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary( "Please correct the errors and try again." )

    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Author )
    @Html.EditorFor( m => m.Author )

    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Question )
    @Html.TextAreaFor( m => m.Question, new { @class = "tinymce" } )

    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Answer )
    @Html.TextAreaFor( m => m.Answer, new { @class = "tinymce" } )
}
```

Here's the model with data annotations:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

In Firebug's console I can validate each element of the form separately:

```
> $('#Author').valid()
true

> $('#Question').valid()
true

> $('#Answer').valid()
false
```

The reason the Answer field is invalid is because it is blank:

```
> $('#Author').val()
"David Bowie"

> $('#Question').val()
"<p>What is my best song?</p>"

> $('#Answer').val()
""
```

However, apparently jQuery validate thinks the form as a whole is valid:

```
> $('form').valid()
true
```

Why is this?

Comment: Is this the only form on your page?

Comment: strange. can you chec the markup generated fro textarea @Html.TextAreaFor( m => m.Answer, new { @class = "tinymce" } ) and see if the ID generated is Answer?

Comment: @jrummell yes it is.

Comment: @HaBo here you go but it's ugly: http://pastie.org/9510986

Comment: @HaBo actually I figured it out. TinyMCE adds "display: none" to the textarea, which the validate function ignores by default: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Comment: Glad you could resolve it

Comment: @Koveras feel free to add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. TinyMCE adds "display: none" to the textarea, which the validate function [ignores by default](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore).